# When exporting to excel file, I want to convert all Hyperlink from gridview into Plain Text

Tags: vb.net, gridview

**What I want:** When exporting to excel file, I want to convert all Hyperlink from gridview into Plain Text..

**Cause:** I am using `HtmlTextWriter` which is why its displaying gridview into HTML inside excel.

following code will export gridview to excel file. I tried using `tostring()` function but it doesnt convert hyperlink into text.

```
Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

            'To Export all pages
            GridView1.AllowPaging = False
            BindGridData()

            ' header rows
            GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White
            For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor
            Next

            ' data rows
            For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
                row.BackColor = Color.White
                For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                    If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                        cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor
                    End If
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode"
                Next
            Next

            GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
            'style to format numbers to string
            Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
            Response.Write(style)
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.[End]()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessage.Text = "error"
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

Basic gridview with cols. 1st col is hyperlink

```
<asp:Gridview id ="GridView1" .... >
   <asp:TemplateField ... >
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:hyperlink ... />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ....
</asp:Gridview>
```

Comment: Try prepending `'` to the string, Excel will force it to be text